# How can I have my Symfony2 bundle use web services created in another bundle?

Tags: angularjs, symfony

We are building an Angular JS / Symfony2 application and are using RESTful web services to pull data to the frontend.

We are also creating an admin (non Angular) to manage some of the data. Instead of maintaining a second set of code that does the data pulls, we think it may be optimal to re-use the REST api calls since they are contractual with known inputs and expected outputs.

From our Admin Controller, is there an easy way in Symfony2 to call the RESTful controller and supply the inputs with different http request types (get, post, put, delete, etc.) and pull the responses back out? We would like to avoid doing a curl request.

In pseudocode:

```
$response = json_decode($request->call('/api/resource', 'post', array('id'=>5)));
// process $response
return $this->render('...view...', array(...));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an HTTP-Client like [Guzzle](https://github.com/misd-service-development/guzzle-bundle) to issue calls to your own *API*.
However I suggest you **not** to do this as you create new unnecessary requests. I would recommend you instead to move all *business logic* from your **Controllers** into separate **Services**. Make these services return simple `Objects` instead of `JSON` and use the contollers in your Bundle only to *transform* these `Objects` into responses. This will allow you to **reuse** the services in your `AdminBundle` as well.